# Attach to process in VS2010 express using a web site. Is it possible?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, web, debugging

I have read this article but it applies to web projects with a .csproj... What about a 'web site'?

http://www.ninjatrader.com/support/forum/showthread.php?t=15671

People at work here tell me to just response.write my way to debug the web sites but I really miss the attach to process that is in the professional edition of vs2010.. or maybe I have to get used to response.write debugging?

(Reason I am not debugging is ektron 8.0 does not compile is vs2010.. so I must attach to process.. or use vs2008)

Comment: There is no "Attach to Process" option in the Express edition.  What kind of company makes their employees work with a free Express edition?  Let us know so we can avoid sending our resumes there.

Comment: Yeah I know there is no attach to process in the express edition. I was hoping there is a workaround. I guess they want to save money and if they can get away with not buying full versions they will.. I understand thier point but I sure do miss being able to debug normally

Answer (score 20):

Visual Studio 2010 Express Edition supports *Attach to process* but it is available only in *Expert Settings*.
Go to **Tools->Settings->Expert Settings**.
After this change, you should see **Attach to Process** button in **Debug** menu.

Comment: Unfortunately not available in the C# version of Visual Studio.

Comment: Yeah.. isn't there in Visual Web Developer expert mode.

Comment: @yoyo, somehow it happens that C# "attach to process" is available via C++ Express 2010 instead. Though the variables evaluation does not seem to work, code stepping (.NET, not just asm) is nicely available via C++ Express 2010 "attach to process".

Answer (score 4):

It isn't available for VS2100 Express. Check the link. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/c6wf8e4z(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: -1: it *is* available, see the answer above. All it takes is to enable expert settings.

Comment: You'd think after 90 years that feature would have eventually trickled down to the Express edition.

Answer (score 2):

An option for websites hosted on another application (Like IIS) is to use the property pages.

**Right Click on Project/Website in Solution Explorer->Property Pages->Start Options**

1. Launch VS2010 Express (or VS2012 Express) ***as Administrator***
2. Set **"Start Action"** radio-button to *"Don't open a page. Wait for a request from an external application."*
3. Set **"Server"** radio-button to *"Use Custom Server"*
4. Set the **"Base URL"** textbox to your site url.
5. Verify the **Debuggers:** *ASP.NET* option is checked.
6. Hit **F5** to launch the debugger, then request the page in the browser.

Then, linking to the website is as easy as pressing the play-debug button and navigating to your url.

*NB: This was tested in VS Express for Web 2012 (ver. 11.0.50727.1) on a Web Site project.*

Answer (score 0):

Just like said in the post above, you can use "Attach to process" in visual studio express. But it's not necessary to change your settings to "expert settings". All you have to do is add the command to the debug menu. 
Tools-> Customize -> Commands -> Menu bar: Debug -> Add Command... -> Debug -> Attach to Process

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

1. right click on toolbar/menu Customize/tab Commands/button Add Command/left list Debug/right list Attach to Process.../button OK/button Close.
2. for me works crtl-alt-p shortcut too.
   .. voila!

Comment: I have this version of Visual Studio 2010:

    Microsoft Visual Studio 2010
    Version 10.0.30319.1 RTMRel
    Microsoft .NET Framework
    Version 4.0.30319 RTMRel
    Installed Version: VC Express
    Microsoft Visual C++ 2010   XXXXX-XXX-XXXXXXX-XXXXX
    Microsoft Visual C++ 2010

and the the instructions, i putted here are correct.

Comment: Unfortunately not available in the C# version of Visual Studio.

Comment: Not available in VS 2010 Visual Web Developer

Comment: @yoyo, somehow it happens that C# "attach to process" is available via C++ Express 2010 instead. Though the variables evaluation does not seem to work, code stepping (.NET, not just asm) is nicely available via C++ Express 2010 "attach to process".