# Attached to process is missing in VS2008 & VS2010 Express

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

In our project we use multiple solutions. each module is a solution. In visual studio 2008 Express and visual studio 2010 Express the attached to process functionality is missing. We can't debug the code.

Comment: This is from MS

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/c6wf8e4z(v=vs.100).aspx its basically because they are EXPRESS, not sure what else you are asking for to be honest

Comment: possible duplicate of [Attach to process in VS2010 express using a web site. Is it possible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4411653/attach-to-process-in-vs2010-express-using-a-web-site-is-it-possible)

Comment: We need to do it using Express edition. In some systems it's really fetching without the "attach to process" functionality. we follow the same but not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this:

[Attach to process in VS2010 express using a web site. Is it possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4411653/attach-to-process-in-vs2010-express-using-a-web-site-is-it-possible)

The option is not available. A real professional shouldn't work with express editions.. IMHO